# How to query on inherited classes with querydsl

Tags: java, mongodb, querydsl

I use querydsl to query on a mongodb. As allowed by mongodb, in several cases I store objects of different types in the same collection.

For instance, in my data model I have:

```
interface Notification {
    NotificationType getType(); // EMAIL, SMS etc.
}

interface EmailNotification extends Notification {
    Set<User> getRecipients();
}
```

Now I want to query for Notifications of any kind (not only EmailNotification), but in the case I have EmailNotifications, I want to filter on some recipient.

I tried this code (doesn't work):

```
final QNotification notification = QNotification.notification;
final BooleanBuilder typesPredicate = new BooleanBuilder();
// "recipientEmails" and "recipientPhones" are provided parameters (lists of String)
typesPredicate.or(notification.type.eq(NotificationType.EMAIL)
                   .and(notification.as(QEmailNotification.class).recipients
                        .any().email.in(recipientEmails)));

typesPredicate.or(notification.type.eq(NotificationType.SMS)
                   .and(notification.as(QSMSNotification.class).recipients
                        .any().phoneNumber.in(recipientPhones)));


notificationPersister.query(Notification.class).where(typesPredicate);
```

It doesn't throw any error or exception, but I don't get the expected result (actually I don't get any result) because the generated mongo query is wrong, and I can't get how to make it right.

Generated query is like:

```
{
   "$and":[  
      // ...
      {  
     "$or":[
        {  
           "type":"EMAIL",
           "notification.recipients.email":{  
              "$in":[  
                 "a@b.com"
              ]
           }
        },
            // ...
     ]
      }
   ]
}
```

And the issue lies in the key "notification.recipients.email": it should be just "recipients.email".

Why does "notification.as(QEmailNotification.class).recipients" translates to "notification.recipients", and how can I make it as expected ?

Note that the following would work:

```
notificationPersister.query(EmailNotification.class).where(
    QEmailNotification.eMailNotification.recipients.any().email.in(recipientEmails));
```

But then I'm forced to run 1 query per inherited class, which is not efficient.

Comment: PS: see also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/querydsl/KaUWIUwov6w

Comment: Fixed via https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/1428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Timo said: Fixed in querydsl via github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/1428